# How to use same JS function on multiple rows of inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an app that will automatically create item names and descriptions by concatenating three columns of information.

Each row is concatenated by using a Javascript function that combines the information but because this function works by using element ID's i am currently having to recreate the function for each row of inputs.

This app needs to be able to handle 100's of rows so i'm wondering if there is a way i can make one function and apply it to every row after clicking on the submit button?

[image]

```js
function method() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value
  var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value
  var input3 = document.getElementById("input3").value

  var description1 = '<b>Product Description</b><br><ul><li>' + 'Color: ' + input1 + '</li><li>' + 'Fabric: ' + input2 + '</li></ul>' +' Style:' + input3

  document.getElementById("description1").innerText = description1

  var name1 = input1 + ' ' + input2 + ' ' + input3
  document.getElementById("name1").innerText = name1

  var input4 = document.getElementById("input4").value
  var input5 = document.getElementById("input5").value
  var input6 = document.getElementById("input6").value

  var description2 = '<b>Product Description</b><br><ul><li>' + 'Color: ' + input4 + '</li><li>' + 'Fabric: ' + input5 + '</li></ul>' +' Style:' + input6

  document.getElementById("description2").innerText = description2

  var name2 = input4 + ' ' + input5 + ' ' + input6
  document.getElementById("name2").innerText = name2

  var input7 = document.getElementById("input7").value
  var input8 = document.getElementById("input8").value

  var input9 = document.getElementById("input9").value

  var description3 = '<b>Product Description</b><br><ul><li>' + 'Color: ' + input7 + '</li><li>' + 'Fabric: ' + input8 + '</li></ul>' +' Style:' + input9

  document.getElementById("description3").innerText = description3

  var name3 = input7 + ' ' + input8 + ' ' + input9
  document.getElementById("name3").innerText = name3

  var input10 = document.getElementById("input10").value
  var input11 = document.getElementById("input11").value
  var input12 = document.getElementById("input12").value

  var description4 = '<b>Product Description</b><br><ul><li>' + 'Color: ' + input10 + '</li><li>' + 'Fabric: ' + input11 + '</li></ul>' +' Style:' + input12

  document.getElementById("description4").innerText = description4

  var name4 = input10 + ' ' + input11 + ' ' + input12
  document.getElementById("name4").innerText = name4
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
 <button type="button" onclick="method()">Submit</button>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Colour</th>
      <th>Fabric</th>
      <th>Style</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="input1" placeholder="input"></td>
      <td><input id="input2" placeholder="input"></td>
      <td><input id="input3" placeholder="input"></td>
      <td><output id="name1"></output></td>
      <td><output id="description1"></output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="input4" placeholder="input"></input></td>
      <td><input id="input5" placeholder="input"></input></td>
      <td><input id="input6" placeholder="input"></input></td>
      <td><output id="name2"></output></td>
      <td><output id="description2"></output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="input7" placeholder="input"></input></td>
      <td><input id="input8" placeholder="input"></input></td>
      <td><input id="input9" placeholder="input"></input></td>
      <td><output id="name3"></output></td>  
      <td><output id="description3"></output></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="input10" placeholder="input"></input></td>
      <td><input id="input11" placeholder="input"></input></td>
      <td><input id="input12" placeholder="input"></input></td>
      <td><output id="name4"></output></td>
      <td><output id="description4"></output></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have your function accept a row element as an argument, and get the inputs from that?

Comment: Side note, there's no such beast as `</input>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cliffe,

This is surely possible by using a clever programming technique called loops.

First, name each input it's own name. For example:

All colours will be: colour1, colour2, colour3, ...

All fabrics will be: fabric1, fabric2, fabric2, ...

And, all styles will be: style1, style2, style3, ...

Do the same for your descriptions and names.

After, we can use a for loop to achieve this:

```
var numTotal = 3
for (i = 1; i < numTotal+1; i++) { 

     var input1 = document.getElementById("colour" + i).value
     var input2 = document.getElementById("fabric" + i).value
     var input3 = document.getElementById("style" + i).value

     var description = '<b>Product Description</b><br><ul><li>' + 'Color: ' + 
     input1 + '</li><li>' + 'Fabric: ' + input2 + '</li></ul>' +' Style:' + input3

     document.getElementById("description" + i).innerText = description

     var name = input1 + ' ' + input2 + ' ' + input3

     document.getElementById("name" + i).innerText = name

 }
```

I would recommend checking out this tutorial if you'd like to learn more about different types of loops in JavaScript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp.

Best,

Dhvani

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
```

```js
function method(){
    // Get all input elements from your site, using document.querySelectorAll
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    // Loop through them, increment by 3 since you have 3 inputs per row
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i+=3){
        // take the 3 inputs you need to generate your values with the loop-index i
        var name = inputs[i].value + inputs[i+1].value + inputs[i+2].value;
        var description = '<b>Product Description</b><br><ul><li>' + 'Color: ' + inputs[i].value + '</li><li>' + 'Fabric: ' + inputs[i+1].value + '</li></ul>' + ' Style:' + inputs[i+2].value;
        //  to get the correct description id, take the index, divide it by 3 and round up
        document.getElementById("description" + Math.ceil((i+1)/3)).innerHTML = description;
        document.getElementById("name" + Math.ceil((i+1)/3)).innerHTML = name;
        
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
 <button type="button" onclick="method()">Submit</button>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Colour</th>
                <th>Fabric</th>
                <th>Style</th>
  <th>Item Name</th>
  <th>Description</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                 <td><input id="input1" placeholder="input"></td>
   <td><input id="input2" placeholder="input"></td>
   <td><input id="input3" placeholder="input"></td>
   <td><p id="name1"></p></td>
   <td><p id="description1"></p></td>
   
            </tr>
            <tr>
   <td><input id="input4" placeholder="input"></td>
   <td><input id="input5" placeholder="input"></td>
   <td><input id="input6" placeholder="input"></td>
   <td><p id="name2"></p></td>
   <td><p id="description2"></p></td>

            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
function new_method(){
 /* selector part of id */
 var count_of_names = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="name"]').length;
 var cur_num=0;
 for (var i = 0; i < count_of_names; i++) {
    cur_num++;
    var input1 = document.getElementById('input'+cur_num).value;
      cur_num++;
    var input2 = document.getElementById('input'+cur_num).value;
      cur_num++;
    var input3 = document.getElementById('input'+cur_num).value;

    var description = '<b>Product Description</b><br><ul><li>' + 'Color: ' + input1 + '</li><li>' + 'Fabric: ' + input2 + '</li></ul>' +' Style:' + input3;
    document.getElementById('description'+(i+1)).innerText = description;
    var name = input1 + ' ' + input2 + ' ' + input3;
    document.getElementById('name'+(i+1)).innerText = name;
 }

}
```

```html
<table id="table">
 <button type="button" onclick="new_method();">Submit</button>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Colour</th>
                <th>Fabric</th>
                <th>Style</th>
  <th>Item Name</th>
  <th>Description</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                 <td><input id="input1" placeholder="input"></td>
   <td><input id="input2" placeholder="input"></td>
   <td><input id="input3" placeholder="input"></td>
   <td><output id="name1"></output></td>
   <td><output id="description1"></output></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
   <td><input id="input4" placeholder="input"></input></td>
   <td><input id="input5" placeholder="input"></input></td>
   <td><input id="input6" placeholder="input"></input></td>
   <td><output id="name2"></output></td>
   <td><output id="description2"></output></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
   <td><input id="input7" placeholder="input"></input></td>
   <td><input id="input8" placeholder="input"></input></td>
   <td><input id="input9" placeholder="input"></input></td>
   <td><output id="name3"></output></td>
   <td><output id="description3"></output></td>


            </tr>
      <tr>
   <td><input id="input10" placeholder="input"></input></td>
   <td><input id="input11" placeholder="input"></input></td>
   <td><input id="input12" placeholder="input"></input></td>
   <td><output id="name4"></output></td>
   <td><output id="description4"></output></td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```